# Why doenst it apply my IE stylesheet?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

If you take a look at: http://www.nrgi-raadgivning.dk/erhverv
You can see in the code, that if you are coming from an IE, it should apply a stylesheet...

The IE stylesheet is supposed to set the margin:0 at the dropdown menu ul, but i doesnt? 
Any ideas to whats wrong?

Comment: Why set the margin:0 only for IE browsers? Are you assuming that other browsers will ALWAYS use 0 for the margin (that assumption could be wrong)? In that case you should place the margin:0 in the general stylesheet to force it for all browsers. In my opinion it is best practice trying to use browser specific hacks as little as possible. I always use a "reset stylesheet" to reset default browser styles (and that is applied for all browsers).

Answer (score 2):

From your markup:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Files/System/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Files/System/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

However, the linked URL returns a "File not found message":

> http://www.nrgi-raadgivning.dk/Files/System/ie7.css

Also, did you mean to link the same stylesheet twice? If so, you should be able to drop the second conditional comment.

Comment: Ok, thats fixed now, but it still doenst apply what is in the stylesheet... 

The IE stylesheet contains:
#menubar ul li:hover ul { z-index:9999; display: block; position: absolute; background-color:#FFF; margin: 3px 0 0 0; border:1px solid #CCC; clear:both;}

But it doenst apply the margin??

Comment: Considering that you already have a `position: absolute`, you could try to use `top: 3px` to apply the vertical offset instead of margin. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Not found is a simple error irrelevant of the content within the CSS.  Make sure your path (/Files/System/ie7.css) is right.